# fatal error call to undefined method MDB2_error::disconnect()

Tags: php, iis, mdb2

I am running a php script in command line that connects to a oracle and mssql to fetch some data and write to a file. Actually it was a cron on linux machine which needed to be transfered to windows 2008.

The command is throwing the error:

> fatal error call to undefined method MDB2_error::disconnect() in
>   path\to\script.php in line63

The code around line 63 are:

```
$db_clw = MDB2::factory($config->database->CLW->dsn);
if (PEAR::isError($db_clw)) {
    $db_clw->disconnect();
    $db_banner->disconnect();
    die($db->getMessage());
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the disconnect method on a `MDB2 error` object. That method does not have a disconnect method.

```
$db_clw = MDB2::factory($config->database->CLW->dsn);
if (PEAR::isError($db_clw)) {
    $db_clw->disconnect();
//           ^ method does not exist
    $db_banner->disconnect();
    die($db->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you call `die` immediately, there is probably no need to use `disconnect` at all, but if `$db_clw` is `MDB2_Error`, it has no method `disconnect`, so you should not attempt to call it.  The attempt to call it will only occur if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

When it throws an error here

```
$db_clw->disconnect();
```

You already know that $db_clw is not a MDB2 Driver, but rather an error.  As such, it doesn't have a disconnect method, so that line should be deleted.
You might want to surround your other disconnect statement there with a try-catch, such as:

```
$db_clw = MDB2::factory($config->database->CLW->dsn);
if (PEAR::isError($db_clw)) {
    //We now know $db_clw is an error, don't attempt to disconnect.
    try {
        $db_banner->disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {} //ignore it.
    //die($db->getMessage()); Not sure if this is what you want, I'd think
    die($db_clw->getMessage())
}
```

ignoring any problems with disconnecting, so that the statement `die($db->getMessage());` is reached, which will help you determine why `$db_clw = MDB2::factory($config->database->CLW->dsn);` is failing.

Just noticed, and updated the code above to change the last statement to `die($db_clw->getMessage());`, which seems, probably, to be what your looking for there.

Comment: You got that right, I needed to find why the error statement was reached. I think it was for environment variable setup problem. I have added the path to pear to the env variables and now its gone.